# How to over ride session_gc() method in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9, I've a requirement to terminiate user session after 10 minutes, I found the session_gc() method in http.py at the root of odoo directory. I want to know how can I over ride this method in my custom module?

```
 import openerp
 import werkzeug.contrib.sessions
 import random
 import time
 import os
 import logging
 _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

 class OpenERPSession2(openerp.http.OpenERPSession):

      def session_gc(session_store):
     _logger.info('-----session   ### ### Management')
     #if random.random() < 0.001:
     # we keep session one week
     #last_week = time.time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
     last_week = time.time() - 60 * 1
     for fname in os.listdir(session_store.path):
        path = os.path.join(session_store.path, fname)
        try:
            if os.path.getmtime(path) < last_week:
                os.unlink(path)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

I over ride this way, but not getting desired result, But When I put these lines in base's http.py file, it was working fine. I dont know why its not working from custom module

Comment: Have you tried a monkey patch?

Comment: No @CZoellner, I've not tried